# rake db:migrate ignores host parameter for production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

When I try to run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` I get an error because it tries to connect to localhost (error: `Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'10.0.0.7' (using password: NO)`)

This is my database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: long-amazon-aws-rds-instance-endpoint
  database: xxxx_production
  username: xxxxx
  password: <%= ENV['XXXX_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

when I run `echo $XXXX_DATABASE_PASSWORD` it gives me the correct password and when I run a `mysql -uxxxxx -hlong-amazon-aws-rds-instance-endpoint -p` and then enter my password I can connect to the RDS no problem. I also have the environment variable set for `passenger` and the app connects fine to it, so the RDS instance is definitely reachable.

Why is rake trying to use the local ip and not the hostname specified in `database.yml`

Answer (score 0):

So turns out you have to wrap the `production` in quotes. If I run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"` it works...